# DAX Default to last value with data

Tags: dax, dimensional-modeling, azure-analysis-services

Presently my data returns:

[image]

What I need it to do is if the current month has 0's, it will default to the last months value with data:

[image]

I know this can be done with nested `IF` statements, but is there a better way?

**UPDATED WITH @TPD SUGGESTION**

The results from @TPD suggestion yield:

[image]

With measure defined as:

```
 IF([Land Dev Alloc] = 0, CALCULATE([Land Dev Alloc],TOPN(1, CALCULATETABLE(Hyperion,FILTER(ALL(Hyperion), [Land Dev Alloc]>0)),Hyperion[DimDateID],DESC)),[Land Dev Alloc])
```

Where `Hyperion` is the main fact table that measure `Land Dev Alloc` pulls from

Comment: I'm guessing you have a date later than what you're showing that returns that value? Try filtering on the date too. Answer updated.

Comment: @TDP, Thank you for the help, this was far simpler than originally assumed. See answer

Comment: I can't see the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way but I've recently solved a similar problem like this, assuming you have a Date table and a Value table joined with a relationship:

```
CurrentOrLastValue:=
CALCULATE (

    -- EXTRACT VALUE FROM ROW
    FIRSTNONBLANK( 'value'[value], 1 ),

    -- FIRST ROW FROM YOUR 'VALUES' TABLE REDUCED TO THOSE BEFORE THE CURRENT CELL DATE
    -- ORDERED BY DATE DESC
    TOPN (
        1,
        CALCULATETABLE (
            'value',
            FILTER
            ( 
                ALL( 'date'[date] ), 
                'date'[date] <= MAX( 'date'[date] )
            )
        ),
        'value'[date],
        DESC
    )
)
```

**Data tables and Pivot Table**

[image: Data tables and Pivot Table]

**Measure**

[image: Measure]

**Relationships**

[image: Relationships]

**UPDATE TO SHOW MEASURE RESULT NOT RAW VALUE**

Add a new core measure (doubling values to show a difference):

```
TotalValue:=SUM('value'[value]) * 2
```

Add a new measure to show desired output:

```
CurrentOrLastValueMeasure:=CALCULATE (
    [TotalValue],
    TOPN(
        1,
        CALCULATETABLE(
            'value',
            FILTER(
                ALL( 'date'[date] ),
                'date'[date] <= MAX( 'date'[date] )
            )
        ),
        'value'[date],
        DESC
    )
)
```

New measure in pivot table:

[image]

**UPDATE TO SHOW LAST NON-ZERO VALUE WHEN MEASURE RETURNS ZERO**

```
LastNonZeroMeasure:=
IF( [TotalValue] = 0,
    CALCULATE (
        [TotalValue],
        TOPN(
            1,
            CALCULATETABLE(
                'value',
                FILTER(
                    ALL( 'value' ),
                    [TotalValue] > 0
                )
            ),
            'value'[date],
            DESC
        )
    ),
    [TotalValue]
)
```

TotalValue not being doubled anymore. Two data points for 4th Jan to show the measure's aggregation working.

[image: last non zero measure]

**UPDATE TO IGNORE DATES AHEAD OF CELL DATE**

Try filtering the dates also...

```
LastNonZeroMeasure:=IF( [TotalValue] = 0,
    CALCULATE (
        [TotalValue],
        TOPN(
            1,
            CALCULATETABLE(
                'value',
                FILTER(
                    ALL( 'value' ),
                    [TotalValue] > 0
                ),
                FILTER(
                    ALL( 'date' ),
                    'date'[date] < max( 'date'[date] )
                )
            ),
            'value'[date],
            DESC
        )
    ),
    [TotalValue]
)
```

[image]

Comment: I am dealing with a measure, not a column in a table

Comment: Can you reformulate to referencing a measure in the Value table instead of a column?

Comment: You've got a different measure for each month?

Comment: No, just the one measure, date dimension, spanning over the horizon. How can I set the column reference to allow for a measure reference

Comment: I guess you need to change your measure to return values for those months that are currently returning zero. My answer hopefully gives you an example of how to do it...

Comment: I only get zeros again

Comment: Want to enter a chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165509/discussion-between-sauron-and-tdp).

Comment: I think it's because my values are 0, as well, not just empty/NULL

Comment: Thank you, I made the change, however, the model  returns as seen above

Comment: I don't understand. All I can see above are your original screen shots.

Comment: Please refresh, I have added the screen cap

Comment: You're getting closer aren't you :) As you haven't included any sample data or the DAX for your measure or the table structure etc I can't really help any further. I notice you've started a new question for the same issue. Good luck finding your final solution!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being far more simple than originally thought:

```
MeasureOne BALANCE YTD:= VAR LastNoneblankDate = CALCULATE(max('Date'[DimDateID]),FILTER(ALL('Date'),'Date'[Fiscal_Year] = MAX('Date'[Fiscal_Year])),FILTER(ALL(FactTable),[MeasureOne] > 0)) return IF([MeasureOne]=0, CALCULATE([MeasureOne],FILTER(ALL('Date'),'Date'[DimDateID] = LastNoneblankDate)), [MeasureOne BASE])
```

Where MeasureOne Base:

```
MeasureOne BASE:= VAR LastNoneblankDate = CALCULATE(max('Date'[Date]),FILTER(ALL(FactTable),[MeasureOne] > 0)) return IF(HASONEVALUE('Date'[Date]),[MeasureOne], CALCULATE([MeasureOne],FILTER(ALL('Date'),'Date'[Date] = LastNoneblankDate)))
```

the main issue was setting ALL(FactTable) instead of jut FactTable and handling the cases with

Comment: Your answer is referencing code that wasn't included in the original question... And it looks to me as though you've used my answer to find your solution.

Comment: I will set yours right as mine is a derivation of what you posted, just the EXACT solution that I used, no worries